# Modelling To-Many Relation To Superclass Object

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I started my work with greenDAO project, which I want to use to simplify database operation in my Android project. So, I would like to create a relation schema in seperated Java generator project.

My aim is to implement a superclass, from which other entities may inherit. Of course, I use a method:

myEntity.setSuperclass("MyCommonBehavior");

for each of inheriting entities. But the question is, how can I set a To-Many Relation to my main ("abstractive") model described in class, instead of setting To-Many Relation to each of specific entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GreenDAO doesn't support [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) for now.

See their docs: [Modelling Entities](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/)

*" [...] Note: currently it’s impossible to have another entity as a super class (there are no polymorphic queries either)*

Anyway, you could implement it yourself storing the entity type and some interfacing.